# How to fill a field by date now from a click of a button

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to fill a field by date now from a click of a button of the action

```
class sale_inheritd(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'
@api.multi
def action_sale_temporary(self):
    for order in self:
        self.env['project.project'].search([('project_id', '=', 'related_project_id')]).write({'temporary_reception_date':datetime.date.today()})
        order.write({'state': 'temporary'})
```

What is the problem with this function?

Comment: It seems that issue is in your domain that you have used in search project `[('project_id', '=', 'related_project_id')` , you passed a string `'related_project_id'` that is wrong because `project id` is relational field so you need a actual id `related_project_id` instead of string so your correct domain will be `[('project_id', '=', related_project_id)]` , but here you don't have variable `related_project_id` , so first find the correct project id else your write is perfect

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand the domain that you have passed to search method but if you want to fill a field with type Date:

```py
   .write({'temporary_reception_date':fields.Date.today()})
```

and for Datetime field:

```py
   .write({'temporary_reception_date':fields.Datetime.now()})
```

**Note:** and don't use `self` to access a field inside the loop exm: `self.related_project_id` use `order.related_project_id` instead or you most likely will have `Singleton` Error

EDITS: as @CZoellner said it's better to `fields.Date.context_today(self)` because that will prevent problems with user timezones

Comment: As already mentioned in another question: i advise to use `Date.context_today()` and `Datetime.context_timestamp()` because that will prevent problems with user timezones.

Comment: totally True @CZoellner

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is not clear what are you trying to accomplish.
Your search method you search for `project_id[looks like many2one field]` equals to a string.

If it is many2one field then pass id to get correct result.
Also make sure `self.env['project.project'].search([('project_id', '=', 'related_project_id')])` returns a single record only else it will lead to singleton error.

If there is only one record returned by search method then there is no issue in writing to the record like you did.

Comment: I did this but problem
self.env['project.project'].search([('project_id', '=', self.related_project_id.id)]).write({'temporary_reception_date':datetime.date.today()})

Comment: Are you sure in model project.project there is only one record that have value 'self.related_project_id.id'. If yes, then in the that record the value of field temporary_reception_date will be changed.

Comment: i don't have ID in sale for project how define field